# Manage vertical overflow of a container in HTML

Tags: html, overflow

I have an HTML structure loike this:

```
<div style="max-height: 520px;">
  <div style="height: 250px;">
    [...]
  </div>
  <div style="height: 250px;">
    [...]
  </div>
    [...]
</div>
```

I would like that my divs behave like in a GridView, goijng into a new column if the maxheight of the main div is reached, like in the 2nd case (sorry for the orrible MS Paint drawing):

[image]

Where the blue box is the main div and the black ones are the secondary. What can I do?

Comment: How do you create your div ? And do you know the exact dimension of the secondary div ?

Comment: Divs are created dinamically with PHP; their numbers depends on an XML that I parse. The height of the main DIV itìs not always known, I'd like to make it ad hoc depending from the user's resolution, but as last solution I'll fix it to about 500px (two little divs); the height of the secondary divs is ALWAYS of 250px.

Comment: ohhh I see now, thanks for clarifying. I would say you have to put these divs columns, and float the columns. Not really that possible the way you are doing it :(

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/m8LgG/

```
<div class="container">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>

.container {
    max-height: 520px;
}

.container div {
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
border: 1px solid #33d;
border-radius: 10px;
float:left;
margin: 0 10px 10px;
}
```

It is best not having inline styles by the way. Try and semantically structure your code :-)

Comment: That is not properly what I meant, try to put in the HTML:

<div class="container">
  <div>
      1
  </div>
  <div>
      2
  </div>
  <div>
      3
  </div>
  <div>
      4
  </div>
</div>

P.S. Inline styles was just for post here in SO, in my html pages I always use CSS ;)